# R: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : numeric 'envir' arg not of length one in intrinsic.pars() in multgee package

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df`with the following data:

```
family_id_cass   twin_order  ls75cat
  10026          1           2
  10026          2           2
  10071          1           3
  10071          2           3
  10132          1           1
  10132          2           2
```

I would like to run `intrinsic.pars()`, so what I am doing is the following:

`intrinsic.pars(df$ls75cat, df$family_id_cass, df$twin_order, rscale="ordinal")` but i get the following error:

`Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`intrinsic.pars()` seems to be written with a very temperamental interface which effectively ignores most of the parameters.  (I suspect this was meant to be an internal function.)  In any case, you have to provide a data.frame to the argument 'data', which includes variables `y`,`id`, and `time`:

```
df <- read.csv(text=
"family_id_cass,twin_order,ls75cat
10026,1,2
10026,2,2
10071,1,3
10071,2,3
10132,1,1
10132,2,2")

newData<-data.frame(y=df$ls75cat,
                    id=df$twin_order,
                    time=df$family_id_cass)

# either of these calls will do:
intrinsic.pars(y,newData,id,time,rscale="ordinal")
intrinsic.pars(data=newData,rscale="ordinal")

#> [1] -3.498327e-07 -1.143481e-10 -5.162827e+00
#> Warning message:
#> glm.fit: fitted rates numerically 0 occurred
```

Comment: The code is still running so far, although I think it is taking a long time. My total sample is only 5,306 observations.

Comment: I also have a question regarding the``id`` and ``time`` variables. The documentation on [multgee](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multgee/multgee.pdf) states that ``id`` is the vector that identifies the clusters. In my case each twin pair is a cluster, so shouldn't ``id = df$family_id_cass`` where the twins have the same ``family_id_cass``? This would mean that ``time = twin_order``.

Comment: However, when I run ``intrinsic.pars()`` this way i get an error: ``Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels``. Do you think my interpretation of the parameters is wrong?